# Reload Content Editor after selecting language using language switcher

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to reload content editor content based on selected language as I need to filter items before user can see them. Right now I am able to filter items by inheriting from BucketDataView and overriding GetChildItems method.

Is there a way to refresh content after selecting new language but after filter is called?

If my approach is wrong, what else can I use?

Thanks!

Lukasz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution

Create a new command

```
[Serializable]
public class SelectLanguage : Languages
{
    public override string GetClick(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context, string click)
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", Sitecore.ItemIDs.ContentRoot));

        return base.GetClick(context, click);
    }

}
```

Update \Website\App_Config\Commands.config

Set `<command name="ribbon:languages" type="[Namespace]SelectLanguage ,[assembly]"/>`

In this case I am able to update content tree after selecting new language in language switcher.

Łukasz.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and works great. It is well explained in one of my favorite post from John West.
[load-or-reload-an-item-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms](http://sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/load-or-reload-an-item-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

You can use it for example inside a Command see [dialoge-box-in-een-command](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/nederlands/dialoge-box-in-een-command/) for some code.

Alternative Use a url, See [open-content-editor-on-specific-item](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/open-content-editor-on-specific-item.html)

Comment: Hi, I am getting error "Empty strings are not allowed. Parameter name: value" at Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load). PS. I didn't create a command, I am trying to utilize GetChildItems from BucketDataView. Any ideas why I am getting that error?